# Easiest Way to Keep Time Synced on VMware Cluster

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, vmware-esxi, ntp

I have a three host VMware cluster (5.1) running mainly windows 2008r2 servers with a single DC.  I'm having allot of problems with time drift across the servers and while I've found several articles ([vmware timekeeping best practices](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1318), [configuring time on windows 2008r2](http://nchrissos.wordpress.com/2013/04/26/configuring-time-on-windows-2008-r2-servers/)) they seem more like hacks then solutions.  What is the simplest most bulletproof (when factoring upgrades patching) solution to permanently rectify this issue ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The VMware article you referenced recommends using the Windows Time (w32time) service configured to sync with NTP rather than the domain hierarchy. (Admittedly, VMware has vacillated a bit on this over the years, but this is the current recommended best practice.) This isn't a "hack"-- it's just a non-default configuration of the w32time service.

Your physical machines will still sync with the virtual Domain Controller (DC) because its instance of w32time will consider itself to be an authoritative time server.